# How do I search a column for any cells with dates earlier than a specific date and highlight them?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm simply trying to search a specific column for any dates earlier than what the user specifies.

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim TheAnswer$
TheAnswer = InputBox("In M/D/YYYY format, enter the first day of the month for which this report is being run." & _
                     vbCr & vbCr & "For example, you would enter ""12/1/2012"" for the December 2012 report.", "Enter Date M/D/YYYY")

For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Cells
    If rCell.Value < TheAnswer Then
        rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
    End If
Next rCell
```

My problem is that this doesn't always pick the right ones.  If I use a month or day with two digits, it completely ignores those months and days with one digit.  I already formatted the cells with the 03/14/01 date format, so they display fine, but the value doesn't match.  Could I simply change what displays to match the value?  If so, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

***Update: With help from Kevin, I was able to solve this.  In case anyone finds it useful, here's my finalized code:***

```
Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Select

Dim rCell As Range
Dim TheAnswer$
Dim ConvertedDate#

TheAnswer = InputBox("In M/D/YY format, enter the first day of the month for which this report is being run." & _
                     vbCr & vbCr & "For example, you would enter ""12/1/2012"" for the December 2012 report.", "Enter Date M/D/YY")
ConvertedDate = CDate(TheAnswer)

For Each rCell In Selection
    If rCell.Value <> "" Then
        If rCell.Value < ConvertedDate Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next rCell
```

Comment: You're comparing actual dates with a string. You need to first create a date from the user-entered value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `TheAnswer` as a string, whereas the `rCell.Value` will be a date, so the results will be inconsistent.  Try this:

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim TheAnswer$
Dim ConvertedDate#
TheAnswer = InputBox("In M/D/YYYY format, enter the first day of the month for which this report is being run." & _
                 vbCr & vbCr & "For example, you would enter ""12/1/2012"" for the December 2012 report.", "Enter Date M/D/YYYY")
ConvertedDate = CDate(TheAnswer)
For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").cells
If rCell.Value < ConvertedDate Then
    rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 0)
End If
Next rCell
```

Also, consider not using the entire column (D:D) and instead use a set range or a dynamic range.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! I tested your code by entering a few different date formats and they all work! I knew I had to be missing something with the date format, but I'm not as familiar with Excel VBA as I am with Word VBA.

I ended up nesting the "if then" statement in another one that checks for (and skips) blank cells, so now it doesn't change the thousands of empty rows in the entire column. I would like to do as you suggested with using a set range or a dynamic range, but I don't know how. I'm going to look that up, but any help would be great.

Comment: OK, I figured out how to get a dynamic range and after some tweaking, I got it do exactly what I needed.  Thanks again for your help.